A tower of Hanoi puzzle
We have disks of n different sizes and for kth smallest size we have $n_k$ disks, with 3 rods as usual, with the same rules as in the classic Tower of Hanoi problem. So for the smallest size we have $n_1$ disks and for the largest size we have $n_n$ disks.
I have encountered a problem where all the disks are considered indistinguishable, but I wondered what about the case when they are distinguishable, as in all disks of a given size can be distinguished between one and another and our objective remains same, to transfer the tower in the exact same pattern from the leftmost rod to the right most rod and find the minimum number of steps.
I thought about this after solving the case when disks of the same size are not distinguishable. If one solves it one gets $a_k=\sum_{r=1}^{k}2^{k-r}n_r$. Here $a_k$ represents the number of steps required for disks of k different sizes.
My approach relied on the fact that the solution, i.e. the steps which one may do to transfer the non-distinguishable disks of the same size, if done to the distinguishable disks, it reverses the order of the stack of largest disks. So if we had our disks of only size upto 2 stacked up as $1_a 1_b 2_a 2_b$, after applying our method we would get a stack of $1_a1_b2_b2_a$
Our whole stack of disks is on left most rod and our objective is to find the smallest no. of steps to transfer it to the right most rod.
My procedure was to take all the disks except the largest disks and put them on the right most rod, with the steps one would use in case of non-distinguishable disks, leading to a reversal. Now take the largest disks and put them on the middle rod, these too are reversed. Now put the stack on the right most disk on the left most disk using the procedure of the indistinguishable disks, leading to another reversal which leads to our original configuration. Now we put all the disks on the middle rod on the right most rod, which leads to them now being in original configuration. Finally, what we do is that we take all the disks on the left most rod and put them on the right most rod but with the procedure to mantain the same configuration, as right now the configuration is the same as original.


  
This implies $b_k=2a_{k-1}+2n_k+b_{k-1}$. And from solving this I got $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{n-k+1}n_k-1$.
Am I correct, is this the shortest way, I have made some arguements to convince myself but I have yet to confirm?

If I understand you right - which is not sure because you have failed to adequately define the conditions of your problem - replace your $n_k$ "distinguishable" disks of the same radius with $n_k$ disks of slightly decreasing radius, all of which lie between the radius of the next larger disk and the radius of the next smaller disk, and your question reduces to the standard Tower of Hanoi problem.

@PaulSinclair Yes, if you were to do that it would reduce to the standard Tower of Hanoi problem. If you are trying to say that my relation of $b_n$ doesn't work for $n_k=1$, you might be correct, since my method accounts for the reversal of the bottom stack, but reversal of bottom stack of one of a single disc has no meaning. Thanks for pointing that out! But now I ask this: Suppose $n_k$ is not equal to 1 for al k, then does my relation hold true? Suppose it doesn't, can you help me figure out where I am wrong, and what other procedure you may have in mind?

What I am saying is that your problem is equivalent to the standard problem, by replacing your distinguishable disks of the same radius with disks of slightly different radii. Under that equivalence, the solution algorithm for the standard problem also provides a solution algorithm for your problem.

@PaulSinclair I do not think that these two are equivalent- the puzzle you mention and the puzzle I asked in the question. Suppose there are 5 disks of the second largest radius. In your puzzle the 5th disk on the bottom cannot go above the 1st disk on the top (both in reference to the disks of the second largest radius) as you have in a sense put a sense of larger and smaller between the 2, but in my case, both can above each other in whatever way. Your puzzle assigns a sense of hierarchy to the disks of the same radius, which leads to the fundamental issue.

I failed to notice you were after the shortest solution which leaves the disks of the same size in the same order in the end. My approach provides a solution for this situation, but admittedly, it is probably the longest possible solution involving no backtracking.

Perhaps, I think that it is the longest solution too, and I believe it may be proven easily too. Do you have any other ideas on how one may tackle this puzzle? @PaulSinclair
